# fallo al registrar usuario en php

Tags: php, formularios

Soy nuevo en esto, cuando registro un usuario me da el siguiente error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\manga\bin\clases.php:23 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\manga\bin\registrar.php(4): Datos->registrar('askeom3@gmail.c...', '12', '12') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\manga\bin\clases.php on line 23,
```

Los códigos son los siguientes

CLASES.PHP

```php
<?php 
    class Conexion {
        protected $base;
        public function Conexion() {
            try {
                $this->base = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=manga', 'root','');
                $this->base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                
                $this->base->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
                return $this->base;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo "Error en la linea: " . $e->getLine();
            }
        }
    }

    class Datos extends Conexion {
        public function Datos(){
            parent::__construct();
        }
        public function registrar($email, $username, $password){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users(email, username, password) VALUES (:email, :username, :password)";
            $statement = $this->base->prepare($sql);
            $statement->execute(array(':email' => $email,':username' => $username,':password' => $password ));
            header('location: ../_admin/panel.php');
        }
    }
?>
```

El segundo es REGISTRAR.PHP

```php
<?php
  require_once("../bin/clases.php");
  $registro = new Datos();
  $registro->registrar($_POST['email'],$_POST['username'],$_POST['password']);
?>
```

Comment: Así como `Datos` extiende `Conexion` ¿Por qué no `Conexion` extiende `PDO`? y te ahorras `$base`.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios problemas de concepto. 
(1) ¿Vas a usar un atributo (propiedad) para la conexión (`$this->base`) o la vas a retornar?
(2) Si vas a usar `return`, no hay variable en `Datos` para recibir la conexión.
(3) En la clase `Conexion` no existe un método `__construct`, no se puede llamar desde `Datos`
(4) Por lo anterior, en ningún momento se inicializa la conexión a la base de datos.

EDIT: Luego de responder, quedé con la intriga de los **métodos** que se llaman igual que su **clase** y en algún lado me parecía haber visto que podían servir de constructores. Y si, PHP menciona algo de que son un viejo estilo, sin embargo, también dice que esa sintaxis [está obsoleta](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) y no se debe usar más. Si estás aprendiendo de un curso, recomiendo lo cambies por otro actualizado.

Entonces, cambiando los constructores viejos por nuevos:

```php
<?php
class Conexion {
    protected $base;
    
    public function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->base = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=manga', 'root','');
            $this->base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->base->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
            //return $this->base; // Propiedad protected, no es necesario return
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Error en la linea: " . $e->getLine();
        }
    }
}

class Datos extends Conexion {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct(); // <-- Iniciar el constructor padre
    }
    
    // ... Otros métodos
}

// ...
```